# Scheduling stuff in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing some research but I can't figure out on how to do this in `Rails`.
I need to execute some code after a certain amount of time. I found some `gems` that can handle this but I don't want to use any.

I basically have a `create` function in a `Rails controller` and some stuff need to happen there after 24 hours.

EDIT: I tried with `sleep` but it needs to be `async` and sleep will stop everything from running until it's done, even if it is in a `if` statement.

Comment: *"I found some gems that can handle this but I don't want to use any."* Any particular reason why? If you do not want to use a gem then you are going to need to handwrite your own implementation (probably creating a cron job) to run this task. There is no native scheduling in ruby or rails which is why the gems exist.

Comment: Oh if there isn't I'll probably use that gem then. But even in native `Ruby` isn't there anything for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an `ActionJob` with `rails generate job your_job_name`.
Then you can delay its execution

```
YourJob.set(wait_until: 1.day.from_now)
```

For this to work you indeed need a Job queue to be configured for your project. I personally recommend [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Sadly, you will have a hard time avoiding setting up a gem for this.

Comment: The answer is **always** Sidekiq.